# ASP.NET Web API in WebForms 404

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I have a controller called "UploadsController". I have a GET action like so:

```
public string GetUpload([FromUri]string action)
{
    return "hey " + action;
}
```

If I navigate to the following API URL in my browser, I get a successful response.

```
http://localhost:52841/MySite/api/uploads?action=testaction
```

However, when I try calling the API from code-behind in my WebForms app, I get a 404 response.

Here's what I have in my Global.aspx file (even though I believe the first should do it):

```
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
    RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "Default2Api",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Uploads", action = "GetUpload" });
```

Here's how I'm calling the API:

```
    // Send a request asynchronously continue when complete 
    client.GetAsync("http://localhost:52841/MySite/api/uploads?action=testaction").ContinueWith(
        (requestTask) =>
        {
            // Get HTTP response from completed task. 
            HttpResponseMessage response = requestTask.Result;

            // Check that response was successful or throw exception 
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Read response asynchronously as JsonValue
            response.Content.ReadAsAsync<string>().ContinueWith(
                        (readTask) =>
                        {
                            var result = readTask.Result;
                            //Do something with the result                   
                        });
        });
```

I thought I've done this before (with the RC version, using RTM now), but I can't seem to get this one.

As a side note, the request isn't showing in fiddler for some reason, which is kind of annoying when you're trying to debug these kind of stuff.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Works on my machine. :-)  
First step is to get Fiddler working here. Take a look at [Rick's post](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Jan/14/Monitoring-HTTP-Output-with-Fiddler-in-NET-HTTP-Clients-and-WCF-Proxies) on configuring Fiddler to work with HttpClient requests.  
Also, as you note, you don't need that second route in your global.asax file. The first one is good enough.

Comment: Tried the web.config method, fiddler still not capturing.

Comment: Ah, now I believe you're hitting the classing Fiddler localhost issue.  Per the Fiddler docs _"Important: Regardless of other settings, .NET will always bypass the Fiddler proxy for URLs containing localhost.  So, rather than using localhost, change your code to refer to the machine name."_

Comment: My page doesn't load/connect when I use the machine name instead of localhost.

Comment: Just to confirm this code also works OK on a quick test harness I put together too. The few other SO questions along these lines usually end up being an rouge trailing "/" at the end of the URL? Is the url in your question the exact URL you are trying to call?

Comment: although it didn't make any difference on my tests you may want to try including an accept header client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); ... also do you have any firewall proxy type products installed and this is along shot but is visual studio running as an admin account (if on win 7)...

It may be worth using a tool like WireShark http://www.wireshark.org/ to see exactly what the request is doing.

Comment: I tried the same setup with a new app, and it worked perfectly. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling the nuget package in my current one but it didn't help...

Answer (score 2):

1. Try naming your query string parameter to something else (Right now it is "action"). I think that's one reason it's causing problems. Since MVC is convention-based, that might be causing problems.
2. Also in your route declaration, try adding the query string parameter (Let me call it **custAction**).
3. And declare custom route before default route.

Code sample:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
name: "Default2Api",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
       defaults: new { controller = "Uploads", action = "GetUpload", custAction = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

Comment: Didn't work. Note, the "custAction" would be passed as a query string parameter - it shouldn't have to be part of the route definition (?) Also, even without the paramter, I get a 404.

Comment: Did you try defining the route definition before the default one?

Comment: I tried swapping them - yes. But again - even without the parameter (and an action with out a param) it gives a 404.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I have been through the same problem most likely your issue is that webapi doesnt allow cross domain calls by default or at least this is what I know about it.

You need to add a CORS support to your web api code, follow the link this guy has shown how to add CORS to your webapi

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CORS-support-in-ASPNET-Web-01e9980a

Good Luck.

Comment: Are you calling your webapi from the same solution? Like are you writing the consumer code in the same solution as the webapi? or webapi is deployed somewhere else and you are using a separate application to consume the webapi if yes, then try its the CORS issue for sure. I had the same issue.. Is your browser showing an error like origin access etc?

Comment: No - in my example I have the web api and client code in the same solution.

Comment: http://localhost:52841/MySite/api/uploads/GetUpload?action=testaction
try this url then.. you are providing the wrong route then

Comment: I mean try removing this defaults: new { controller = "Uploads", action = "GetUpload" } from your second route and use this  defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional } instead and then try calling this url.

localhost:52841/MySite/api/uploads/GetUpload?action=testaction

I hope it helps.